# Why is LLVM's Optional<T> implemented this way?

Tags: c++, nullable

I stumbled upon an implemenation of `Optional<T>` which is based on LLVM's [Optional.h](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Optional_8h_source.html) class and couldn't quite figure out why it is implemented the way it is.

To keep it short, I'm only pasting the parts I don't understand:

```
template <typename T>
class Optional
{
private:
    inline void* getstg() const { return const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_stg)); }
    typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type storage_type;
    storage_type _stg;
    bool _hasValue;

public:

    Optional(const T &y) : _hasValue(true)
    {
        new (getstg()) T(y);
    }

    T* Get() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(getstg()); }
}
```

And the most naive implementation I could think of:

```
template <typename T>
class NaiveOptional
{
private:
    T* _value;
    bool _hasValue;

public:
    NaiveOptional(const T &y) : _hasValue(true), _value(new T(y))
    {
    }   

    T* Get() { return _value; }
}
```

Questions:

1. How do I interpret the `storage_type`?  what was the author's intention?
2. What is the semantics of this line: `new (getstg()) T(y);` ?
3. Why doesn't the naive implementation work (or, what pros does the `Optional<T>` class have over `NaiveOptional<T>`) ?

Comment: 1) aligned memory for T (see [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)), 2) placement new, 3) pros of optional over naive: you save a dynamic allocation.

Comment: As far as #2 goes: it's called *placement new* and it basically tells `new` to construct the object at a specific place that you have previously allocated.

Comment: P.S: In your naive implementation the boolean is redundant, you can just compare to nullptr to know if you have a value or not.

Comment: It's about avoiding a very costly dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks. Maybe this belongs in a different question, but what bad things might happen if the memory wasn't aligned?

Comment: @Shmoopy afaik aligned loads are faster in at least some (if not all) cases, also I *think* some platforms require loads to be aligned.

Comment: @Shmoopy: unaligned loads might be less efficient, or the load will truncate the address (reading wrong data), or the CPU will fault and either kill the process or require really expensive emulation of an unaligned load. Thats what some of the existing architectures I know do, the standard just plainly says "its undefined"

In short, its not portable, and if you use a recent clang or gcc you can use sanitizers to warn about his.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is "performance".

Longer answer:

1. `storage_type` provides an in-memory region that is (a) big enough to fit the type T and (b) is aligned properly for type T. Unaligned memory access is slower. See also the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).
2. `new (getstg()) T(y)` is a placement new. It does not allocate memory, but instead it constructs an object in memory region passed to it. The [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) (on all forms of `new` - search for the "placement new").
3. The naive implementation does work, but it has worse performance. It uses dynamic memory allocation, which often can be a bottleneck. The `Optional<T>` implementation does not use dynamic memory allocation (see the point above).

Answer (score -1):

Std::optional is supposed to be returned from functions. That means you would have to store the content referenced by the pointer somewhere. This defeats the purpose of this class

Further, you cant just use plain T, because otherwise you would have to construct it in some way. Optional allows the content to be uninitialized, some types can't be default constructed.

To make the class more flexible in terms of supported types, a fitting and correctly aligned storage is used. And only if optional is active, the true type will be constructed on it

What you had in mind is probably something like std::variant?